# c++ refencing MSVCP140.dll vs MSVCP140d.dll

Tags: c++, dependencies, redistributable

I wrote a small dll to call a 3rd party dll in C++ and my dll and the 3rd party dll are compiled in release mode.

When I use dependenciesGui to to check dependencies, I can see my dll and the 3rd party dll are referencing MSVCP140.dll, VCRUNTIME140.dll and VCRUNTIME140_1.dll. And these dll loads correctly on my machine.

However when I copied the same files to another machine and dependenciesGui shows these dlls are referencing the debug version SVCP140D.dll, VCRUNTIME140D.dll and VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll. and I see the dll load problem "The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" when using DllImport in C#.

both machines have Visual c++ redistributable 2015-2022 installed on windows 10

Any hint what happened? Thanks

**Edit**: It looks like the parent folder need to be called any thing except Debug, and DependciesGui now shows the non-Debug VC dlls. If the parent folder is named Debug, and it then looks for the debug VC dlls.

**Edit 2**: the root problem was the 3rd party dlls were the debug version. However DependciesGui shows my dll was referencing the debug VC dlls even it was compiled in release build.

Comment: @drescherjm, my dll was compiled in release mode, but why on one machine it references the non-debug VC dlls, and another machine it references the debug version of the VC dlls?

Comment: I am not sure why it would reference debug dlls.

Comment: My first suspicion would be that you didn't copy the files you thought you did, that you copied files from a debug build instead.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir pls see my comment. it looks like it relates to the name of the parent folder